# PHP script not waiting for MySQL stored prcedure to complete

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am calling a MySQL stored procedure through PDO, after which I'm sending a report mail.

The problem is that sometimes the stored procedure take longer to execute, and I end up getting the wrong report in mail.

```
$db2->query("CALL sp_endtime()");

Sending mail using php .......
```

I thought PHP was synchronous, and I expected the email to be sent only after query completion. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: It depends on what your stored procedure returns. Also, which PHP interface are you using to issue the `CALL` query? PDO, MySQLi?

Comment: I am using PDO_MYSQL. It does not return output.

Comment: Clarified meaning, massaged title

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT SLEEP(<seconds>);
```

to delay your procedure for this many seconds. As in your case, using

```
SELECT SLEEP(<0.2>);
```

would be just fine.